# How to specify authentication info to memcache with django?

Tags: django, memcached

I use rediscloud to provide memcache support to my django install. 
It allows to set SASL authentication username and password (not sure if the sasl thing could be an issue).

I didn't found the correct syntax to supply them from django:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache",
        "LOCATION": "pub-memcache-********.com:17****",
        "username": "user",
        "password": "pass"
    }
}
```

What's the correct syntax then ?

EDIT:

Installed PyLibMCCache instead, but I can't connect:

In settings.py

```
os.environ[ 'MEMCACHE_SERVERS' ] = 'pub-****:****'
os.environ[ 'MEMCACHE_USERNAME' ] = '*'
os.environ[ 'MEMCACHE_PASSWORD' ] = '*'

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': 'pub-****.com:****',
        'BINARY' : True,
    }
}
```

error:

> error 3 from memcached_get(:1:ddd-37041): (0x1068af060) CONNECTION
>   FAILURE, ::rec() returned zero, server has disconnected,  host:
>   pub-***.com:** ->
>   libmemcached/io.cc:484

When I disable authentication, I don't get this error.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use an external library for that:

https://github.com/django-pylibmc/django-pylibmc

`pip install django-pylibmc`

Their README explains it:

> Django has direct support for pylibmc. [...]
>   Two reasons to use django-pylibmc instead are:
>
> - You need to use the binary protocol
> - You need to use a username and password to access the memcached server (such as with Memcachier on Heroku).

Comment: I did so indeed. But I can't have it catch username and password.  I tried to add this in settings.py os.environ[ 'MEMCACHE_USERNAME' ] = '*'
os.environ[ 'MEMCACHE_PASSWORD' ] = '*' or MEMCACHE_USERNAME = '*'
MEMCACHE_PASSWORD = '*' and it closes my connection.

Comment: According to the code, that should be enough, see https://github.com/django-pylibmc/django-pylibmc/blob/master/django_pylibmc/memcached.py#L70-L71 . I would try to debug it inserting a breakpoint around there.

Comment: how would you set  params.get('USERNAME') ? Where would you put USERNAME ?

Comment: 'params' is basically what you put in the CACHES setting for that backend. But I think that you have already tried that. Django initializes the backend here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/__init__.py#L55

Comment: Have you tried to use upper case ? So USERNAME instead of username in your settings dict.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the rediscloud people:

> in some environments,binary protocol with authentication is required
>   where bmemcached module which supports memcached binary protocol with
>   authentication.
>
> We request you to please try resolving the error by using
>   django-bmemcached.
>
> To do so, install django-bmemcached:
>
> pip install python-binary-memcached
>
> and,
>
> pip install django-bmemcached
>
> Next, configure your CACHES in the settings.py file:

```
import os
import urlparse
import json

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_bmemcached.memcached.BMemcached',
        'LOCATION': '******.com:1****',
        'OPTIONS': {
                   'username': 'user',
                   'password': 'pass'
            }
    }
}
```

This works, and allows access to their memcached server with authentification.

So this is yet another alternative to work with memcached.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a username and password on your memcached cache, then you should switch to the PyLibMCCache binding, as shown below. As of Version 1.11 Django has out-of-the-box support for the PyLibMCCache binding (and thus pylibmc). Older Django versions require that you install django-pylibmc.

The usual django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache does not support passwording.

So here is an example using PyLibMCCache and user authentication:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'binary': True,
                    'username': 'my_username',
                    'password': 'my_password',
                }
    },
}
```

The django documentation notes:OPTIONS: *Any options that should be passed to the cache backend. The list of valid options will vary with each backend, and cache backends backed by a third-party library will pass their options directly to the underlying cache library*. [options docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES-OPTIONS)

so looking in the pylibmc v1.6.0 documentation  we see the following:
*username and password are credentials for SASL authentication. It requires support in libmemcached, and binary=True. Test for local support with pylibmc.support_sasl.* [pylibmc reference docs](https://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/reference.html)

for a general overview of memcached and django see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#memcached

And for a description of the settings available in pylibmc see: http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/

Note the password and username and data returned will all be in plain text as noted here by memchaced.org:
*Also even with SASL, a VPN or TLS in the form of stunnel still needs to be used, since auth and all other content will be sent over plaintext*.  see [memcached/issues/184](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/issues/184)